# Unable to create searchbar for infinity-scroll data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, infinite-scroll

I have spent so much time trying to figure out how to make infinite scroll work with a searchbar in Angular. I am using Angular 9 and ngx-infinite-scroll for infinity scrolling. I figure out how to make it work for pure infinite scroll when searchbar input is empty. It is scrolling and calling back-end for more items - everything perfect. The problems occurs when I write something in the searchbar, then the event (scrolled) won't be fired and function LoadMoreData() also. I need to fix this for scenarios when I put something in the searchbar and then I clear it - in both of them it's not working. I was trying different things, but I couldn't make it happen.

There is my code (HTML & Typescript) from component:

```js
export class TaskMarketComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
  @ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('lastTaskCard', { read: ElementRef }) lastTaskCard!: ElementRef;

  public taskList: TaskDto[] = [];
  public filteredTaskList: TaskDto[] = [];
  public tasksLength: number;
  
  private isNewSearchQuery = false;
  private searchQuery$ = new Subject<string>();
  private pageIndex = 1;
  private pageSize: number;
  private hasMoreData = true;
  private lastTaskId: number | null = null;

  searchQuery: string = '';

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.calculatePageSize();
    this.loadTasksWithSearchResult(this.searchQuery).subscribe(r => {
      this.processTask(r);
    })
    this.searchQuery$
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((searchQuery) => {
        this.pageIndex = 1;
        return this.loadTasksWithSearchResult(searchQuery);
      })
    )
    .subscribe((task) => {
      this.taskList = [];
      this.processTask(task);
      this.setFocusOnSearchInput();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.searchQuery$.unsubscribe();
  }

  searchTaskList(): void {
    this.pageIndex = 1;
    this.taskList = [];
    this.isNewSearchQuery = true
    this.searchQuery$.next(this.searchQuery);
  }
  
  private loadTasksWithSearchResult(searchQuery?: string): Observable<TaskListDto> {
    const filters = this.fillTasksFilters(searchQuery);
    return this.taskService.getTasks(filters);
  }

  private fillTasksFilters(searchQuery?: string): TaskFilterDto {
    return {
      filters: {
        taskId: null,
        recipientFullName: '',
        name: '',
        name: '',
        createdDate: '',
        executionDate: '',
        status: ''
      },
      pagination: {
        pageNumber: this.pageIndex,
        pageSize: this.pageSize
      },
      sort: {
        column: '',
        asc: true
      },
      searchQuery: searchQuery ?? this.searchQuery
    };
  }

  private setFocusOnSearchInput(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.searchInput) {
        this.searchInput.nativeElement.focus();
      }
    }, 0);
  }

  private processTask(tasks: TaskListDto): void {
    tasks.data.forEach((task) => {
      task.TaskId = task.TaskId;
    });

    if (tasks.data.length <= 0) {
      this.hasMoreData = false;
    }

    if (this.searchQuery) {
      this.filteredTaskList = tasks.data;
    } else {
      this.taskList = this.taskList.concat(tasks.data);
      this.filteredTaskList = this.taskList;
    }
  
    this.tasksLength = tasks.totalElements;

    const lastTask = tasks.data[tasks.data.length - 1];
    this.lastTaskId = lastTask ? lastTask.TaskId : null;

    if (this.lastTaskId && !this.isNewSearchQuery) {
      const lastTaskCard = document.getElementById(`taskCard_${this.lastTaskId}`);
      if (lastTaskCard) {
        lastTaskCard.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    }
    this.isNewSearchQuery = false;
    this.pageIndex++;
  }

  private calculatePageSize(): void {
    const screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
    this.pageSize = Math.ceil(screenHeight / 200);
  }

  loadMoreData(): void {
    if (this.hasMoreData) {
      this.loadTasksWithSearchResult(this.searchQuery)
        .subscribe((task) => {
          this.processTask(task);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="tab-list-content">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center table-title-row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-12 search-bar">
        <input type="text"
               #searchInput
               placeholder="Search"
               class="form-control"
               [(ngModel)]="searchQuery"
               (ngModelChange)="searchTaskList()"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div #scrollContainer class="scroll-container" infinite-scroll (scrolled)="loadMoreData()">
      <div *ngFor="let task of filteredTaskList; let last = last" class="card" [attr.id]="'taskCard_' + task.TaskId" #lastTaskCard >
        <div class="row card-body">
          <!-- some card body -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

this.hasMoreData should be set to true whenever the search query is being changed:

```js
switchMap((searchQuery) => {
        this.pageIndex = 1;
        this.hasMoreData = true;
        //rest of the code
      })
```